# How to make Lubuntu's Temperature Monitor applet report the real temperatures?

Tags: lubuntu, temperature

Lubuntu's Temperature monitor always reports 40°C and never changes. Resource Monitor reports my CPU hovering between 80% and 98% for about 1.5 days now and Temperature Monitor hasn't changed even though I can hear the CPU fan whirring dutifully as it changes speed to accommodate my demands.

Other posts recommend installing `lmsensors` and running `sensors-detect` and running `sudo modprobe`, all of which I have tried without results. Even after rebooting, no change is seen in Temperature Monitor.

[image: It never changes]

Right clicking Temperature Monitor and choosing settings gives the following fields and values. I haven't the first clue as to what might be appropriate for the "Sensor" field, or what "Automatic sensor location" might mean:

[image: settings panel]

Comment: its probably your device. post the output of "sensors"

Comment: It's a question of hardware: if your hardware doesn't have any sensors, it cannot report on them...  Post the output of `sensors-detect` .

Comment: Related: [Correct sensor location to use for Temperature Monitor in lxpanel?](https://askubuntu.com/q/229929/37165) that has recent answers; one with an example location (likely hardware dependent).